# When running Selenium tests on the command line, how do I execute a command only if that element is visible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm using selenium-side-runner v 3.11.0 to attempt to run a test against a Chrome browser from teh command line.  How do I wait to execute a command until an element is visible (note: not "present" but visible).  I was reading this -- https://ui.vision/docs/selenium-ide/waitforvisible -- and thought "waitForVisible" could work, but when I insert this in my ".side" test ...

```
 {
"id": "fbf35ed7-1a28-4540-a93d-3cb8ba0e012a",
"comment": "",
"command": "waitForVisible",
"target": "id=user_login",
"targets": [],
"value": ""
}
```

It dies with the below error ....

```
localhost:selenium davea$ PATH=/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/starter_project/selenium/dev/:$PATH selenium-side-runner --headless -c "browserName=chrome" /tmp/81a312ad-8fe1-4fb0-b93a-0dc186c3c585.side
info:    Running /tmp/81a312ad-8fe1-4fb0-b93a-0dc186c3c585.side
 FAIL  ./DefaultSuite.test.js (5.462s)
  Default Suite
    ✕ myTest (3726ms)

  ● Default Suite › myTest

    Unknown command waitForVisible

      12 |     return element.click();
      13 |   });
    > 14 |   throw new Error("Unknown command waitForVisible");
         |         ^
      15 |   await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(`user_login`)), configuration.timeout);
      16 |   await driver.findElement(By.id(`user_login`)).then(element => {
      17 |     return element.clear().then(() => {

      at Object.<anonymous>.tests.myTest (commons.js:14:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (DefaultSuite.test.js:11:5)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.595s, estimated 6s
```

Comment: Is this Selenium IDE or Selenium Webdriver? You have both tagged so you should remove one.

Comment: I recorded the test (created the ".side" file) using Selenium IDE and am running it on the command line using various webdrivers (chromedriver for Chrome, geckodriver for Firefox, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

selenium-side-runner (the command line runner) seems to be broken in this regard. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/643